# Fetch an SQL Object relating to a PostgreSql database on the Azure java API

Tags: java, azure

I have an Azure resource group, and I want to be able to fetch a specific relating to my PostGreSQL server in my to my Resource Group.

In the Azure Java SDK (1.1.0), I want to fetch

```
URL l_resourceUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResource("azureauth.properties");

final File credFile = new File(l_resourceUrl.getFile());

Azure azure = Azure.configure().withLogLevel(LogLevel.NONE)
            .authenticate(credFile).withDefaultSubscription();

azure.getAzurePortalHandle().sqlServers();

for (SqlServer lt_gr : x.list()) {
    System.out.println(lt_gr.name());
 }
```

Unfortunately the postgresql server does not show up among this list (obviously), but I do not see any other option that would provide me with a PostgreSQL server object that can allow me to fetch server info provided by Azure, such as ip-addresses, compute units stc...

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks

Baubak

PS: Afterword : As suggested I have already used Generic Resource, but it seems to be quite restrictive in regards to the server information suchs as : Server State, Status, Performance Configuration etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Azure SDK for Java, the postgresql server is belong to `GenericResources`, not `SqlServers` (just Azure SQL Database).

Here is my sample code to list all PostgreSQL resource in a resource group.

```
Azure azure = Azure.configure().withLogLevel(LogLevel.NONE)
        .authenticate(credFile).withDefaultSubscription();
String resourceGroupName = "<your-resource-group-name>";
String providerNamespace = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL";
Iterator<GenericResource> iter = azure.genericResources().listByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName).iterator();
/*
 * List all resource without resource group
 * Iterator<GenericResource> iter = azure.genericResources().list().iterator();
 */
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    GenericResource gr = iter.next();
    if (providerNamespace.equals(gr.resourceProviderNamespace()))
        System.out.println(gr.name() + "\t" + gr.resourceProviderNamespace() + "/" + gr.resourceType());
}
```

If you want  to fetch a specified postgresql resource, as the code below.

```
String resourceGroupName = "<your-resource-group-name>";
String providerNamespace = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL";
String resourceType = "servers";
String resourceName = "<your-resource-name>";
GenericResource gr = azure.genericResources().get(resourceGroupName, providerNamespace, resourceType,
            resourceName);
System.out.println(gr.name() + "\t" + gr.resourceProviderNamespace() + "/" + gr.resourceType());
```

Meanwhile, the all above codes works when you have the permission of some roles like `Contributor`, please see the document [`Use Role-Based Access Control to manage access to your Azure subscription resources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure) to know how to configure.

---

Update: Here is my sample code for listing server parameters of postgresql.

```
String resourceGroupName = "<your-resource-group-name>";
String providerNamespace = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL";
String resourceType = "servers";
String resourceName = "<your-resource-name>";
String apiVersion = "2017-04-30-preview";
String postgresConfigurationURL = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%s/resourceGroups/%s/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/%s/configurations?api-version=%s";
String url = String.format(postgresConfigurationURL, subscription, resourceGroupName, resourceName, apiVersion);
System.out.println(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + cred.getToken("https://management.azure.com/"));
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
br.close();
```

The output as below.

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "value": "on",
                "description": "Enable input of NULL elements in arrays.",
                "defaultValue": "on",
                "dataType": "Boolean",
                "allowedValues": "on,off",
                "source": "system-default"
            },
            "id": "/subscriptions/ed0caab7-c6d4-45e9-9289-c7e5997c9241/resourceGroups/so-v-jiapa/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/peterpostgres/configurations/array_nulls",
            "name": "array_nulls",
            "type": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/configurations"
        }, ...]
```

[image]

The internal url comes from a command `az postgres server configuration list --resource-group <your-resource-group-name> --server-name <your-postgres-name>` of the [Azure CLI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) tool.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks,  I had used Generic Resource, but the it does not give a lot of access to the properties of the Server.  I want information such as : Performance Configuration, Server State and Server Parameters

Comment: @BaubakGandomi By now, there is not any existing method of Azure SDK for Java to get these information as you said, but you can get them via some internal REST APIs. Please see my sample code for listing server parameters.

Comment: Thanks this will actually help :)

Comment: Not yet. Will give the rest call a try. I tried fetching the properties for the GenericResource, but they were also empty, so I think Rest is the way.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PeterPan-MSFT It worked just fine once I got the authentication working :D